# Map Object Values to Another Object with Specific Model Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array of objects that I receive from API that looks like this:

```
Array [
  Object {
    "OPTIONNUMBER": "1",
    "OPTIONVALUE": "Here is your name ",
  },
  Object {
    "OPTIONNUMBER": "2",
    "OPTIONVALUE": "Footer",
  },
  Object {
    "OPTIONNUMBER": "3",
    "OPTIONVALUE": "https://google.com",
  },
]
```

how to map it to an object with a specific name as `[OPTIONNAME]: OPTIONVALUE`;

the model looks like this:

```
export interface IOptions {
  opt1NAME: string;
  opt2FOOTER_TEXT: string;
  opt3LINK: string;
}
```

the end result should be like this:

```
const options = {
  opt1NAME: 'Here is your name';
  opt2FOOTER_TEXT: 'Footer';
  opt3LINK: 'https://google.com';
}
```

I am trying `map` and `assign` but can't come up on how to properly map the names of the objects.

edit1:

```
//appOptions here is an array of string that contains names
let options = {};
for (let i = 0; i < appOptions.length; i++) {
      Object.assign(options, {[appOptions[i]]:arr[i].OPTIONVALUE });
    }
```

this works as giving me the right object but it not typed correctly.

Comment: Your desired end result doesn't seem like a particularly useful structure, the original array seems much more flexible. What are you actually trying to do with your output?

Comment: the output would be saved in context and later used as an object structure. ex: `context.options.opt1NAME` or `context.options.opt2NAME` is easier than searching through array or other structure every time I would need to get an option (or getting it by index).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
const options = [];
const op = ["opt1Name","opt2FOOTER_TEXT","opt3LINK"]
// you can list all your needed options in op and it will work
for (let index = 0; index < x.length; index+=3) {
    const option:{[key:string]:any} = {};
    // x is the name of your api result
    const elements = x.slice(index,index+3);
    elements.forEach((ele,idx)=>{
        option[op[idx]]=ele.OPTIONVALUE
    })
    options.push(option)    
}
```

Comment: this should work without ifs @denistepp

Answer (score 0):

the solution was to create an empty object with empty content (it will be used for context anyways):

```
export const initOptions: IOptions = {
  opt01FOOTER: '',
  opt02FOOTER_TEXT: '',
  opt03LINK: '',
}
```

then in function where we want to restructure:

```
let options: IOptions = initOptions;
const keys = Object.keys(options) as Array<keyof IOptions>;

//arr is the array with names and values
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  //Object.assign() works here as well
  options[keys[i]] = arr[i].OPTIONVALUE;
}
```

now we can easily use `options` with descriptive names:

```
console.log(options.opt02FOOTER_TEXT);
```

if the number of options increases, we have to add one more entry to model and one empty key-value pair to the `initOptions`

I was trying to find a solution around the creation of empty object, open for better solution with typed `options`